# android - handling notification from gcm server

Tags: android, django, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have an android app which registers to gcm and i have a server side which sends request to the GCM service and the gcm sends a message to the device.

it works fine.

my question is about the google docs:

From what I understand from the google docs there is a difference between a data message and a notification message - https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http.

[image]

I have it working fine with the data message, I have a service in my app which shows a Toast with the data.

**My question is:**

I want my app to receive the message as a notification, like a facebook/gmail/any other app notification (a small row message in the top of the screen).

- Does that have something to do with the notification/data message from the gcm (in the google docs)? Is there a difference between them? or its all about how I deal with the message when it arrives?
- If its all about how I deal with it, how do I show it as a notification like the other apps?

for now I just have a `Toast.makeText` which shows the data (even when the app is closed, obviously - from the service).

If it matters - my server side is in django (python).

Comment: at mobile side for showing notification on top in notification panel you have to do all that for reference  http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Comment: thanks for your answer! I did get it to work, but is only shows the icon in the top of the screen, it doesn't drop a small row from the top of the screen that disappears after a few seconds, (like watsapp for example). it only adds the notification to the notifications panel (when you swipe down). any help?

Comment: i am not clear but are you looking for notification introduced in material design(lollipop) check this on will help you http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

Comment: I think it's a `Heads-up Notification`: If a notification's `priority` is flagged as `High, Max, or full-screen`, it gets a heads-up notification. Please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) and search `Heads-up Notification`.